# \listoffigures problem

Tags: table-of-contents

As a part of my thesis, I am using `\listoffigures` to display the list of figures. Now, some of the figures have `\footnote` in their captions. To display the `\footnote`s properly, I have used the suggestions of: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ftncapt
Now when I go to the `\listoffigures` I see, for this figure: `[Caption for LOF] ....... 39`. What I should see is: **map and encap scheme**, Which is the actual caption for the figure. How can I fix this?

The 2nd problem is regarding CLICKABLE link in `\listoffigures`. For example, for the entry,

```
2.3 Traffic Engineering Scenario ............ 24
```

The whole caption is CLICKABLE. But for another entry with `\cite` in it:

```
2.4 Compact Routing Example [24] ................ 29
```

Only the citation number [24] is CLICKABLE. I can't click **Compact Routing Example**.

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be very complicated. Could you please edit your post and add a [minimal (non)-working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. That way, you can be much easier helped.

Comment: Robin has updated the FAQ to make this clearer. (You may recognise the example used!)

Comment: For information, the question has been crossposted: [\listoffigures problem](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=19883).

Answer (score 5):

Where the FAQ has

```
\caption[Caption for LOF]%
  {Real caption\footnote{blah}}
```

You are not supposed to use "Caption for LOF" as literal text, but rather use a simplified caption, without `\footnote` (and perhaps without `\cite`)

so....

```
\caption[Compact Routing Example]
        {Compact Routing\footnote{something} Example \cite{abc}}
```